# How to sort by relation by latest created_at column where has many in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, relational-database

I have two tables "inventory" and "sell_records" relationship. Each product in inventory has many sell records.
I need to order all products by the latest sold record. So, I need to find out the latest sell record for the product from all sell records that the product has and then sort all the products.

This is the script I came up with, but it still doesn't sort as it should be.

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('inventory.client_id', $user->client_id)
                                        ->join('inventory_sell_records', 'inventory_sell_records.product_id', '=', 'inventory.id')
                                        ->groupBy('inventory_sell_records.product_id')
                                        ->orderByRaw("max(inventory_sell_records.created_at) $order_by")
                                        ->paginate(100);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using :

```php
$inventory = Inventory::where('inventory.client_id', $user->client_id)
  ->join('inventory_sell_records', 'inventory_sell_records.product_id', '=', 'inventory.id')
  ->groupBy('inventory_sell_records.product_id')
  ->orderBy("inventory_sell_records.created_at", "desc")
  ->paginate(100);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).